# How to get firmware for a router that is not supported by the manufacturer anymore?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, firmware

I have a very old router which I do not use anymore, this model:
zyxel p-2602hwn-d7a

It is branded by the provider O², therefore I cannot use it with other ISPs. It should be possible with an upgraded firmware directly from the manufacturer, at least some people were able to do that quite some years ago.

Unfortunately all download links I could find are dead. Is there any chance for my old router, or should I throw it out? Is there an alternative use for it?

Comment: Toss it and upgrade.

Comment: I would amend to "bring it to an electronics recycler" .  If you're in the USA, bring it to Staples and they'll recycle small electronics for you for free.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Thanks. I am in Germany though and my city provides recycling facilities for electronics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately... no. ([did you try the internet wayback machine?](https://archive.org/web/web.php)) or asking them via email or phone if they have an archive?

The [WiKiDevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ZyXEL_P-2602HWN-D7A) page for it shows it having 8MB of flash storage. This would make it compatible for a DD-Wrt micro version, but its dev page shows its CPU as {CPU1: TI TNETD7200ZDW}... [It is based on a Texas Instruments (TI) chipset](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Known_incompatible_devices)

It looks like [someone over at OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/toh/zyxel/zyxel_p2602hwn) was looking into this router for OpenWRT firmware support, but it also looks like they gave up a long time ago...(2016)

I have to agree with Moab here, you can find a router that will utterly destroy this in performance for 5-10 dollars U.S...

On the other hand, you could always use it for a 4-port switch.

Comment: Thanks! Will give the Wayback Machine a try just for fun. If it fails, I can at least throw it out without feeling bad about it.